# Keep filter data in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a page with table of some data (let's say posts). I have a form there which leads to the same page but with get parameters. So when I choose December in dropdown list form will lead to posts/index?month=december. Controller index method makes eloquent query using query string parameters to filter rows. After that I click edit post(or add new post) and change something through edit form. Then update or store method redirects back to index as usually. What is the best way to come back to index?month=december page? Sessions? How should I do it? Set some values from query to session in Controller index method when I come there first time and get them also in Controller method from session after editing/creating?

Comment: Would redirect()->back() let you keep the query params?

Comment: @mrhn You don't chain `back()` with `redirect()`, you just do `return back();`, or `return redirect('route');`. But I think at the point you're suggesting, `back()` would return to the edit form, and not the `index`.

Comment: @TimLewis you can use what ever method you want to redirect back ... `back()` is `redirect()->back()` and so is `Redirect::back()`, people can do what ever they prefer :)

Comment: @lagbox Oh, that actually works? My bad; I thought `redirect()` needed a param to work. But my comment is more on the fact that `back()` likely isn't referencing the right URL when called from the `edit` form submit.

Comment: @TimLewis yea back is probably an edit form and not the index ... but yea `redirect()` with no arguments returns the Redirector, a lot of the helpers have this type of setup, when no arguments are passed a base object is returned, but with argument(s) is a shortcut to a method on that object

Comment: @TimLewis yes, back() will go back to form. I need to use double back() in some way :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to append all request parameters in the redirect:

```
return redirect()->route('route_name',['month' => request()->get('month')]);
```

You can read more about this in this section in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-named-routes).